# HTTP BOSH and HTTP pipelining

Tags: java, http, web, xmpp

I am confused about HTTP BOSH and HTTP Pipelining.

BOSH spec: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0124.html

> If the client needs to send some data to the connection manager then
>   it simply sends a second request containing the data. **Unfortunately
>   most constrained clients do not support HTTP Pipelining** (concurrent
>   requests over a single connection), so the client typically needs to
>   send the data over a second HTTP connection.

And in this specification is many info about HTTP pipelining, but from 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining

> Non-idempotent methods like POST should not be pipelined.

And in BOSH spec:

> All information is encoded in the body of standard HTTP POST requests
>   and responses. Each HTTP body contains a single  wrapper which
>   encapsulates the XML elements being transferred (see  Wrapper
>   Element).

So how can be HTTP pipelining used with HTTP BOSH??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [HTTP RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1.2.2) says

> Clients SHOULD NOT pipeline requests using non-idempotent methods or non-idempotent sequences of methods (see section 9.1.2).

"SHOULD NOT" in this context has the meaning given by [RFC 2119](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt), namely,

> This phrase, or the phrase "NOT RECOMMENDED" mean that there may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances when the particular behavior is acceptable or even useful, but the full implications should be understood and the case carefully weighed before implementing any behavior described with this label

What this means is that, in general, it is not recommended to use HTTP pipelining in conjunction with `POST` requests (this being in line with [RFC 2616's](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5) notion of `POST`); however, the HTTP protocol does not actually forbid it. If it actually forbade the behavior, RFC 2616 would use the language "MUST NOT". The author's of the `BOSH` spec made a judgement that, in the case of `BOSH` there are no adverse effects to pipelining `POST` requests.